# Game programming books?

Tags: software-engineering, graphics-programming

I need a book that's beneficial for me and not something that contains what i have already read.

I have a strong maths,physics background and I have good c++ programming skills

and i  want to start game programming in 2d because after a lot of research on net people recommend not to jump in 3d directly.

Also I don't want to study from online tutorials like those in SFML because there is lot of knowledge scattered on the net but what i want to study from a good book because in the book all knowledge is in one place

I have also done research that books like Beginning 2d game programming by Charles Kelly,Game Engine Architechture,Game Coding Complete,Advanced 2d game development by Jonathan Harbour are all good **But I can Only Buy one** at the moment and i already know c++,physics and maths pretty well (dont know graphics though) so which one is the right one for me.
So please guide me
Thank You

Comment: -1 If it's been asked, why ask again? Have you read the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq)?

Comment: because i am confused

Comment: If you know C++ already get [this one](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1133776574/ref=as_li_qf_sp_asin_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeASIN=1133776574&linkCode=as2&tag=byte56-20). There are a lot of books that try to teach coding at the same time. You want to focus on game development fundamentals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only know Game Engine Architecture and Game Coding Complete. Both aim for 3d game development. But the core concepts (event handling etc.) are applicable to 2d game as well.

I recommend Game Coding Complete. Shaffry has a ton of experience developing games. He also explains the concepts really well and has C++ code examples.

Game Engine Architecture feels a bit incomplete as it only explains subsystems required for a game. Well worth a read though.

I could be wrong, but from your question I think you don't know how to start game development.

Just pick a library for drawing 2d graphics and start coding.

Start coding a main game loop, load and draw a sprite, capture user input and apply it on screen. Then you want to look up entities and component system etc.

Research stuff as you encounter it. One of the books is a good starter.

Hope that helps.